# PROCESS macro for SPSS - output includes values of the DV which are outside of scale range

Tags: regression, spss

I'm running a moderated moderation model (model 3 of PROCESS macro for SPSS) in order to explore a three-way interaction, with one independent variable, one dependent variable, and two moderators. I'm having trouble with the output, as the dependent variable is represented by a 1-7 scale, however, the data produced for visualising conditional effects appears to generate negative values and values larger than 7 at certain levels of the IV and moderators.

I'm wondering if someone can explain why this might be occurring and if there is anything I can do to avoid this?

[image]

Comment: As you are only evaluating moderation, not mediation, with a simple ordered outcome scale like this you would be better off using [ordinal logistic regression](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/spss/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/), including the interaction terms you want to evaluate, and avoiding the PROCESS macros completely.

Answer (score 1):

The values in the graph input data you get for your dependent variable (the Cons_SCL column) are predicted values from your model, i.e. they are what the model *predicts* your dependent to be at different levels of combinations of your predictors. PROCESS uses OLS estimation so it estimates the line that minimize the errors, regardless of how far this line falls from some observations. So predicted values (values falling on the best line) can be outside the range of the actual values of your dependent.

I try to illustrate this visually (using just a simple moderation for the example). Imagine you had data like this:

[image]

The y variable values are between 1 and 7, and x values are between 5 and 10. In addition, there is a categorical moderation variable M with 2 levels, A and B.

Now, if you fit regression lines for the x-y relationship moderated by M, see what happens:

[image]

The model-predicted value for y when x is 2 is about -1 for group A, even though raw y is bound between 1 and 7. Also, for group B, the predicted value of y when x is 1 is above 7.

I suggest you plot the interaction with raw values in the background to get an idea of why some predictions are so far from raw values. It may mean that the model does not fit very well to your data.